# Determine the 'owner' of an object

Tags: c++

I want to determine which object *'owns'* some other object.
I have a situation similar to the code below. Filling in the blanks, it compiles and seems to do what I expect - but will this work in general? Is there some idiomatic way to do this? Or is ill-advised altogether?

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct A { int blah; /* ... */ };
struct B : A { /* ... */ };
struct C { vector<A> as{{}}; /*.. */ };
struct D { vector<C> cs{{}}; /*.. */ };

const A& superFoo(vector<reference_wrapper<const A>> alsoa) { alsoa.back();}
int main() {
    B b{};
    D d{};

    const A& ds_a = /* Some selected 'a' from 'd' */;
    vector<reference_wrapper<const A>> sfIn = {ref(b), ref(dads)};

    auto out = superFoo(sfIn){ /* Some special selection process, based on A's attributes. */};

    void* address = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&out);
    
/* Here I want to attribute which object, b or d, 'owns' the returned 'a' - 'out' */
if (address < reinterpret_cast<void*>(&b) + sizeof(b) &&
    address >= reinterpret_cast<void*>(&b)) 
       { cout<< "b";
if (address < reinterpret_cast<void*>(&d) + sizeof(D) &&
    address >= reinterpret_cast<void*>(&b)) 
       { cout<< "d"; }

}
```

Comment: This is going to be incredibly fragile and brittle. Generally, `reinterpret_cast` is a no-no unless you *really* know what you're doing, and even then you should still be wondering if it's the best option.  My recommendation would be to, in `A`, keep a reference back to the owner and set that whenever the value is added to either data structure.

Comment: In this case, I don't have control over A's definition, hence this construction. I guess your point is that the idiomatic way to show ownership is to store a reference in the owned object.
On the matter of the reinterpret_cast - I don't think there's any risk involved here since the address is never dereferenced, and used only for pointer arithmetic  - I used it to silence compiler warnings - Is it still unsafe in that case?

Comment: The `B` case *might* be safe (I'm not familiar enough with the addressing rules of C++ to say for certain, but it's possible `B` is guaranteed to be contiguous). The `D` case is unsafe. The `D` class contains a `vector`, which is probably a size integer and a pointer to the actual array data. The actual array data itself is *not* stored in `D` but is hidden behind that pointer, so it's not going to fall within `&d` and `&d + sizeof(D)`. There may be some optimizations in place that make this work for small vectors, but it definitely won't when the vectors get large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that each of the struct A through D all are composited in memory.  Honestly, the real problem here is, how on earth do you come up with that pointer you are feeding to superfoo to begin with?  If it came from one of your objects, then can you not tag it as such.

That's really a design problem.  In general, C++ simply isn't designed to determine if an object is in a particular graph, but if you must, then:

To do this correctly, you would need to define something like so:

(Warning, this is off the top of my head)

```
struct PlainOldDataOnly
{ 
   bool isMe(char *x) { return x >= (char *)this && x < (char *)this + sizeof(PlainOldDataOnly); }
}

struct HasVectors : PlainOldDataOnly
{
   vector<myPlainOldData> stuff;
   bool isMe(char *x) { return PlainOldDataOnly::isMe(x) || (x >= (char *)stuff.data() && x < (char *)(stuff.data() + stuff.size()); }
}
```

Note that in HasVectors, you would have to have that construct of stuff for every vector, and then, it could only work if and only if:

a) The vector(s) consists of only plain old data.
b) The vector(s) are not resized.

As others have said, this is very brittle code.  The moment you put a map, a string, or something else into the objects in the vector, then you will run into problems.  This would be a real pain to maintain.